# how can i rank elements in a csv file from lowest to highest?

Tags: python, ranking

I have a csv file that has a district, party, votes, states, and year rows. I want to rank every district from texas from the lowest number of votes to the highest number of democratic votes only from the year 2018, how can I achieve this in the most beginner code? Would I have to use selection/ insertion sort?

Comment: what is most beginner code mean? is it homework? what are your attempts? please specify `csv` format using a code-style.

Comment: Use `pandas` library

Answer (score 0):

I would use bubble sort, it is the simplest algorithm for sorting numbers.

```
def bubble_sort(your_list):
    has_swapped = True

    index_of_votes_value = 0 #assuming the list is 2D, each year, and then within the year, the votes, party, etc.

    num_of_iterations = 0

    while(has_swapped):
        has_swapped = False
        for i in range(len(your_list) - num_of_iterations - 1):
            if your_list[i][index_of_votes_value] > your_list[i+1][index_of_votes_value]:
                # Swap
                your_list[i][index_of_votes_value], your_list[i+1][index_of_votes_value] = your_list[i+1][index_of_votes_value], your_list[i][index_of_votes_value]
                has_swapped = True
        num_of_iterations += 1
```

This algorithm iterates through your list, it checks if each index is larger than the one after it, and if it is, it swaps them. It keeps going through the list until the list is in order.

Comment: If you're a beginner, or any other kind of programmer, you should just use the built-in sorting functions of Python instead of trying to implement your own.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so but I thought that the way I put it is easier to understand for a beginner than the other answer.

Comment: I didn't learn how to use bubble sort in class so that's why I asked if I could use insertion or selection sort

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this using Java (not sure how beginner friendly it is), you could do something like

```
String s = Files.readString(pathToYourFile);
```

and then split the string into an array of strings, delineated by the new line character "\n".

Then you can parse the String into an object, delineated by the character "," since it is csv. Now you can make a List, and do a Collections.sort(yourList).

Or, you could use a SQL database :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would personally do it:

```py
with open('data.csv') as f:
    file_content = f.read()


data = [line.split(';') for line in file_content.splitlines()]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)

print('\n'.join(';'.join(x) for x in sorted_data))
```

Comment: I didn't learn how to do with open something as but is that the same thing as doing this: inpfile = open('filename.csv', 'r')                                                                                                         datareader = csv.DictReader('filename')

Comment: Using `with open(...) as f: ...` is the same as doing `f = open(...)` and then `f.close()` afterwards. This is called a context manager, and for file management, this is a preferred way to handle it.